# Loading chunk module failed: Upgrade to angular 7

Tags: angular, iis, angular7, upgrade

My application is hosted on IIS. After upgrading to Angular 7, I'm getting the error "Loading chunk module failed".
It seems instead of fetching the files from dist/ folder, its trying to fetch from the root folder.
The .js files are getting created inside the dist/ folder.

[image]

This is my index.html:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ABClth</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "abc": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "targets": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/site.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "abc:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "abc:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "abc:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "abc-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "abc:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "abc:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "abc"
}
```

This is my ts.config file.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the public path:

```
publicPath: '/vuebundles/',
```

/vuebundles/ would be your application folder name. when you host the angular app under the site in iis you have to specify the public path.

another way is you could use iis URL rewrite extension and add the below rule in web.config file:

```
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

  <rewrite>

    <rules>

      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">

        <match url=".*" />

        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

        </conditions>

        <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp/" />
    
      </rule>

    </rules>

  </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```